# Can I visit the USA again?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, visa-refusals, esta, tourist

I left the USA voluntarily after 3 months stay on a credible fear asylum granted at the airport on a tourist visa. I did not wait to appear in Court.

It has been 10 years and now I am a citizen of the United Kingdom. My question is will I be allowed to visit the USA on a tourist visa on vacation back or apply for a ESTA?

Comment: Why do you think you might not be allowed to visit?

Comment: Were you really in fear of returning to your home country at the time you applied for asylum? Did you return to your home country after you left the US?

Answer (score 9):

> will I be allowed to visit the USA on a tourist visa on vacation back or apply for a ESTA?

You haven't said anything that suggests you might be inadmissible.  The only way to know for sure whether you'll be allowed in is to apply for ESTA, and if it's refused apply for a visa, and then if either of those is granted travel to the US and apply for admission.